# Aggregation - Unwind multiple fields

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have some input data :

```
    Brand   | Model   | Number
    Peugeot | 208     | 1
    Peugeot | 4008    | 2
    Renault | Clio    | 3
    Renault | Megane  | 4
```

I would like for each line to have a new column with the sum of each company (in order to get the percentage of a model for a given brand) :

```
Brand   | Model   | Number | Total
Peugeot | 208     | 1      | 3
Peugeot | 4008    | 2      | 3
Renault | Clio    | 3      | 7
Renault | Megane  | 4      | 7
```

I tryed to do somethong like that but it didn't work :

```
  {
    $group: {
      _id: { Brand: "$Brand" },
      Model: { $push: "$Model"},
      Number: { $push: "$Number"},
      Total: { $sum: "$Number" }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: 
      path: ["$Model", "$Number"]
  }
```

Is there a way I can do my aggregation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below aggregation in 3.6.

[`$$ROOT`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/#variable.ROOT) to access the whole document followed by [`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) to add Total field to document and [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) and  [`$replaceRoot`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/) to promote the merge document to the top.

```
[{"$group":{
  "_id":{"Brand":"$Brand"},
  "data":{"$push":"$$ROOT"},
  "Total":{"$sum":"$Number"}
}},
{"$unwind":"$data"},
{"$addFields":{"data.Total":"$Total"}},
{"$replaceRoot":{"newRoot":"$data"}}
]
```